# Consultar dos apis a la vez

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Buenas noches tengo un problema para consultar una información, consumo una api la cual me trae datos correctamente, el detalle es y no sé si lo estoy implementando bien, ya que trato de llamar otra api con la cual consumo un parámetro de la primera para consultar datos de la segunda y es ahí donde en el modal donde precargo la información no me devuelve nada, cabe mencionar que en el segundo consumo de mi api guardo la información en un array, ya que uno de mis formularios es dinámico y tengo que mostrar los `n` registros en base al primero.

**Ejemplo**:

Muestro datos de una institución y en el mismo formulario quiero mostrar datos de contacto de esa misma institución pero no me trae nada me muestra todo en blanco pero si omito el segundo consumo de la api funciona todo bien.

Codigo:

```js
openDialogInstitucion(institucion: InfoInstitucionAll, asesor: InfoAsesorAll,  bandModifi: boolean ) { 
    this.bandModifi = bandModifi;
    this.show_btn = false;
    if (this.bandModifi) {
      this.institucionall = {...institucion};
      this.asesorall = {...asesor};
      this.apisInstitucionesService.getDetailInstitucion(this.institucionall.id_institucion).subscribe({
          next: (response) =>{
            for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
              const element = response[index];

              this.m_id_institucion = element.id_institucion;
              this.m_rfc = element.rfc;
              this.m_razon_social = element.razon_social; 
              }
            this.dialogInstitucion = true; 
            },
          error: (e) => {
            console.error(e); 
              this.dialogInstitucion = false;
              this.institucion = {};
              this.asesorall = {};
              this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: '¡Error de carga!', detail: 'Hubo un error al obtener información de la institución.', life: 3000});
          },
          complete: () => console.info('complete') 
        };
        this.apisAsesoresService.getDetailAsesorPorInstitucion(this.m_id_institucion).subscribe({
        next: (response) =>{
          for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
            const element = response[index];
            console.log(element)
            let json = {
              nombre: element.nombre,
              apellido_paterno: element.apellido_paterno,
              apellido_materno: element.apellido_materno,
            }
            this.informacion_Contacto.push(json);
            console.log(json)
          }
        },
        complete: () => console.info('complete') 
       }
      );
      );
       }
       
       this.openDialogInstitucion({},{},false); //Lo uso para abrir el modal
```

El código de la ventana modal es:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="dialogInstitucion" [style]="{width: '80%'}" [modal]="true">
    <p-header>
        <span>{{ show_btn ? 'Modificar institución' : bandModifi ? 'Ver institución' : 'Registrar institución'}}</span>
    </p-header>
    <p-tabView styleClass="tabview-custom" [(activeIndex)]="TabActivo" [scrollable]="true">
        <p-tabPanel>
            <ng-template pTemplate = "header">
                <i class="pi pi-building mr-2"></i>
                <span>Datos de la institución</span>
            </ng-template>

        <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col-12 md:col-3">
                <label class="font-bold">RFC (*)</label>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    pInputText 
                    pKeyFilter="alphanum"
                    required
                    autofocus
                    [(ngModel)]="m_rfc"
                    [maxlength]="13"
                    placeholder="Ingrese un RFC"
                    class="uppercase"
                    [disabled]="!bandModifi ? show_btn : !show_btn"
                    [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty' : submitted && !m_rfc}"
                >
                <small class="ng-dirty ng-invalid" *ngIf="submitted && !m_rfc">Campo requerido.</small>
            </div>
                <div class="field" *ngIf="rechazotextarea && bandModifi && show_btn">
            <textarea 
                pInputTextarea 
                placeholder="Agregar un comentario" 
                autoResize 
                rows="3" 
                cols="30"
                class="text-justify"
            >
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
        <ng-template pTemplate = "header">
            <i class="pi pi-user mr-2"></i>
            <span>Contactos de la institución</span>
        </ng-template>

        <p-toolbar styleClass="mb-4">
            <div class="col-6 md:col-3">
                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-plus-circle" class="p-button-success p-button-sm border-none mr-2" pTooltip="Agregar nuevo contacto" tooltipPosition="bottom" (click)="AddNuevoAsesor()"></button>
            </div>
        </p-toolbar>
        <section class="container border mb-1" *ngFor="let asesor of informacion_Contacto; let i = index;">
            <div class="col-12 relative" style="top: 45px; right: 0;">
                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-danger p-button-sm border-none absolute top-0 right-0" pTooltip="Eliminar contacto" tooltipPosition="bottom" (click)="DeleteAsesor(i)"></button>
            </div>
            <p-fieldset legend="Contacto ({{i + 1}})" [toggleable]="true" [transitionOptions]="'15ms'">
                <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Tipo de asesor</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [options]="select_tipo_asesor" 
                            [(ngModel)]="asesor.tipo"
                            optionLabel="nombre"
                            optionValue="value"
                            placeholder="Elije tipo asesor">
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                        </p-fieldset>
        </section>
    </p-tabPanel>
    </p-fieldset>
</p-tabView>

    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
        <button pButton pRipple label="Cancelar" icon="pi pi-times" class="p-button-danger p-button-sm border-none" (click)="hideDialogInstitucion()" pTooltip="Cerrar ventana" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
        <button pButton pRipple label="Modificar" icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-primary p-button-sm border-none" pTooltip="Modificar institución" tooltipPosition="bottom" *ngIf="bandModifi && !show_btn" (click)="show_btn = true"></button>
        <button pButton pRipple label="Guardar" icon="pi pi-save" class="p-button-primary p-button-sm border-none" pTooltip="Guardar institución" tooltipPosition="bottom" *ngIf="!bandModifi ? !show_btn : show_btn" (click)="saveInstitucion(bandModifi); show_btn = false"></button>
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

Comment: Pero si esto es angular!! Mi editor de texto favorito me informa que tienes etiquetas sin cerrar y justo en el código que no muestra (por ejemplo esta parte  <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">) Lo otro que a la vista me parece raro es ="'15ms'", me parece que esas comillas simples sobran. Luego lo reviso con más detalle

Comment: Asi es amigo es angular, de igual forma no se si se pueda poner todo el codigo html por que es muy extenso pero si recorte algunas cosas por que no creo que entre todo, deja lo trato de meter.

Comment: Amigo @Yussef ya quedo amigo, era la parte del HTML donde mandaba los parámetros, en él .ts recibía, pero no enviaba, y ya con esa parte quedo solucionado, muchas gracias por tu tiempo amigo.

Comment: Me alegro que hayas podido solucionar el tema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedo simplemente era un detalle de enviar el parametro, ya que lo recibía en el .ts pero no lo enviaba por eso los detalles de visualizar la info.

```js
this.menuToolbar = [
      {
        label: 'Agregar', 
        icon: 'pi pi-plus-circle',
        title: 'Agregar nueva institución',
        styleClass: 'successButton',
        command: () => {
          this.openDialogInstitucion({},{},false);
        }
      }
  ]
```

```html
<button [style]="{width: '25px', height: '25px'}" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-rounded p-button-info mr-1" (click)="openDialogInstitucion(institucion, institucion, true)" pTooltip="Editar institución" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
```

En el .ts recibo los parámetros y ya con eso quedo solucionado, por experiencia no creo que me deje cerrar la pregunta hasta después de dos días, así que pasando ese tiempo lo daré como bueno.

**Gracias a todos por su tiempo.**